# Can't disable multibyte string input conversion for Drupal 8 install

Tags: php, drupal, centos, whm

I've installed a lot of Drupal sites and never had this problem before. On attempting to install 8.1.2 I get an error that says:

> Multibyte string input conversion in PHP is active and must be
>   disabled. Check the php.ini mbstring.http_input setting. Please refer
>   to the PHP mbstring documentation for more information.

The `.htaccess` file that comes with Drupal already has a section that should disable this:

```
# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value assert.active                   0
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
  # PHP 5.6 has deprecated $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and produces warnings if this is
  # not set.
  php_value always_populate_raw_post_data   -1
</IfModule>
```

I've tested and this .htaccess file is used. The server is running a new installation of CentOS 7 with cPanel/WHM. I also changed the PHP settings (using WHM) to:

```
; http input encoding.
mbstring.http_input = pass

; http output encoding. mb_output_handler must be
; registered as output buffer to function
mbstring.http_output = pass
```

Though I don't think that's notably different than what the defaults were. I checked that this was the actual php.ini file used. I have restarted Apache.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to **enable** the mbstring extension.